# sqlIte exception:table not found Exception in android

Tags: android, android-intent, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to android.I am trying to read the database and put result into the List activity.following is entry activity.

```
  package com.sanjay.listdemo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    }

//    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//      Intent intent = new Intent(this, );
//      Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
//      intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
//      startActivity(intent);
//    }

    public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employees WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.simple_list_item, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.firstname, R.id.lastname, R.id.title});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package samples.employeedirectory;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "employee_directory2";

    protected Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String s;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "1", 2000).show();
            InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql);
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
            NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
            for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
                s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                db.execSQL(s);
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**sql.xml**

```
<sql>
<statement>
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    firstName VARCHAR(50), 
    lastName VARCHAR(50), 
    title VARCHAR(50), 
    department VARCHAR(50), 
    managerId INTEGER, 
    city VARCHAR(50), 
    officePhone VARCHAR(30), 
    cellPhone VARCHAR(30), 
    email VARCHAR(30), 
    picture VARCHAR(200))
</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(1,'Ryan','Howard','Vice President, North East', 'Management', NULL, 'Scranton','570-999-8888','570-999-8887','ryan@dundermifflin.com','howard.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(2,'Michael','Scott','Regional Manager','Management',1,'Scranton','570-888-9999','570-222-3333','michael@dundermifflin.com','scott.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(3,'Dwight','Schrute','Assistant Regional Manager','Management',2,'Scranton','570-444-4444','570-333-3333','dwight@dundermifflin.com','schrute.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(4,'Jim','Halpert','Assistant Regional Manager','Manage',2,'Scranton','570-222-2121','570-999-1212','jim@dundermifflin.com','halpert.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(5,'Pamela','Beesly','Receptionist','',2,'Scranton','570-999-5555','570-999-7474','pam@dundermifflin.com','beesly.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(6,'Angela','Martin','Senior Accountant','Accounting',2,'Scranton','570-555-9696','570-999-3232','angela@dundermifflin.com','martin.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(7,'Kevin','Malone','Accountant','Accounting',6,'Scranton','570-777-9696','570-111-2525','kmalone@dundermifflin.com','malone.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(8,'Oscar','Martinez','Accountant','Accounting',6,'Scranton','570-321-9999','570-585-3333','oscar@dundermifflin.com','martinez.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(9,'Creed','Bratton','Quality Assurance','Customer Services',2,'Scranton','570-222-6666','333-8585','creed@dundermifflin.com','bratton.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(10,'Andy','Bernard','Sales Director','Sales',2,'Scranton','570-555-0000','570-546-9999','andy@dundermifflin.com','bernard.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(11,'Phyllis','Lapin','Sales Representative','Sales',10,'Scranton','570-141-3333','570-888-6666','phyllis@dundermifflin.com','lapin.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(12,'Stanley','Hudson','Sales Representative','Sales',10,'Scranton','570-700-6666','570-777-6666','shudson@dundermifflin.com','hudson.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(13,'Meredith','Palmer','Supplier Relations','Customer Services',2,'Scranton','570-555-8888','570-777-2222','meredith@dundermifflin.com','palmer.jpg')</statement>
<statement>INSERT INTO employees VALUES(14,'Kelly','Kapoor','Customer Service Rep.','Customer Services',2,'Scranton','570-123-9654','570-125-3666','kelly@dundermifflin.com','kapoor.jpg')</statement>
</sql>
```

I am getting "No such table found:emplyees".please can anyone suggest me where I am wrong.since 48 hours I am trying to solve this.

Comment: Are you running it on real device or virtual emulator? Real device needs .metadata named dummy table sometimes.

Comment: its a virtual emulator

Answer (score 2):

Don't close your database on each statement when creating the database:

Turn this:

```
for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
  s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
  db.execSQL(s);
  db.close();
}
```

Into this:

```
for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
  s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
  db.execSQL(s);
}
```

The database should not be closed at all in the `onCreate` method.

The fact you are not getting an error when trying to execute the second statement makes me believe you are not executing the statements correctly.

PS: Also I strongly advise you turn your `rawQuery` into proper Android `SqliteDatabase` query

PS2: You should also close your `in` `InputStream`.

Comment: @riyaahuja did you check you actually execute the expressions?

Comment: @riyaahuja I see the code. Add logging and check you actually execute the updates in `onCreate`

Comment: can I have your email Id so that you can have a look what excatly I am doing and why I am getting this error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28213/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-riya-ahuja)

Comment: @riyaahuja I think it is not up to restarting eclipse. Rather to uninstalling the app. The way you wrote your `onCreate` method it will succeed even if error is thrown. However, once it succeeds the database will not be recreated in consequent reruns. Thus you had an erorr initially, but after you fix it you need to uninstall to force recreating of the database.